# Trying to update values in oracle db through Spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to write code that takes in an object, and if it already exists in the db, then update some of the values in the row that maps to that object's ID.  It works to insert new rows into the table, but when I want to update a row, I get this error:

Caused by: org.springframework.dao.IncorrectUpdateSemanticsDataAccessException: Failed to update entity [Video(videoId=10,30,35,112,-127,-72,79,-71,-32,99,116,-77,90,10,-28,-23, name=Test Name 1, description=Test Description, tags=Test Tag, url=Test url, active=1, createdBy=testcreator, createdDate=2023-11-14 13:55:24.682, updatedBy=testupdator, updatedDate=Tue Nov 14 17:30:00 GMT 2023)]; Id [10,30,35,112,-127,-72,79,-71,-32,99,116,-77,90,10,-28,-23] not found in database

Here is the code for my serviceImpl

```
public Video insertVideoInDB(Video newVideo){
        Date date = new Date();
        //check if this is an update
        if(newVideo.getVideoId() != null){
            Video existingVideo = videoRepository.findById(newVideo.getVideoId()).get();
            //then update the updated date and updated by and whatever else changed
            existingVideo.setUpdatedBy(newVideo.getUpdatedBy());
            existingVideo.setUpdatedDate(date);
            return videoRepository.save(existingVideo);
        }
        //new video
        else{
            newVideo.setCreatedDate(date);
            newVideo.setUpdatedDate(date);
        }
        return videoRepository.save(newVideo);
    }
```

Here is my test case for upating(I got the id from the db since I already inserted a video in the table)

```
@Test
    void testUpdates(){
        Video video = new Video(
                "0A1E237081B84FB9E06374B35A0AE4E9", //id
                "Updating", //name
                "Test Description",  //desc
                "Test Tag",  //tags
                "Test url",  //url
                1,           //status
                "testcreator", //who created
                null,      //date created
                "new updater", //who updated -----only val i change here to test
                null //date updated
        );
        videoServiceImpl.insertVideoInDB(video);

    }
```

I am using sys_guid() to generate the id in the table.  I am able to print out the existing video object in the table and the ids match, but I am wondering if this issue may be due to the id created by sys_guid being RAW and I the ID in the video obj is a string?

Comment: Side note: We don't typically unit test a database.  Actually, what you are attempting here strictly is an _integration_ test.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> Here is my test case for upating(I got the id from the db since I already inserted a video in the table)

Actually, you never saved your entity in the database before calling the test method, but you did manually assign an ID.  Therefore, the lookup of this entity against the underlying table using your manual ID will fail.

A correct test case would *not* assign any ID, as the entity has not yet been saved:

```java
@Test
void testUpdates() {
    Video video = new Video(
            null,
            "Updating", //name
            "Test Description",  //desc
            "Test Tag",  //tags
            "Test url",  //url
            1,           //status
            "testcreator", //who created
            null,      //date created
            "new updater", //who updated -----only val i change here to test
            null //date updated
    );
    videoServiceImpl.insertVideoInDB(video);
}
```